# Need Shortcut in MS Word: Shift + 'Space' = comma followed by space in text

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

Pretty much I'm taking notes and it'd make my life easier if I could list two things INSTEAD of "Bob and George went to the farm" as "Bob, George went to the farm."

I want to make a Microsoft Word (and also Google Docs if anybody knows how to do that too, but that isn't as essential) shortcut or macro or something which, by hitting Shift+'Space' results​ in a comma followed by a space, producing what I want above^^^ slightly quicker.

Comment: I recommend you reivew the site guidelines for using Stack Overflow in the [help]. You'd probably be better off asking this on Super User...

Comment: With a key combination that includes an actual character rather than a space, you can set this up in AutoCorrect.

Answer (score 0):

MS Word don't allow to use Shift+Space for any shortcut even macros. You can use Ctrl+Space instead.